# Нужно поменять setTimeout(function() на if(миниатюра создан и сохранен успешно)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, settimeout

После `setTimeout(function()` открывается Dialog | jQuery UI

Нужно открыть: если миниатюра успешно создан, сохранен и читаемый, без таймеров.

html:

```
<div style="display:none;" id="dialog">
    <video id='myVideo' controls></video>
</div>
```

script.js

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/video/upload_video.php?saveCanvas=1",
            data: {
                imgBase64: dataURL,
                thumbnailName: thumbnailName,
                uploadFolder: uploadFolder,
                success: function() {
setTimeout(function() {
                        myVideo.currentTime = 0;
                        myVideo.load();
                        myVideo.poster = 'siteURL' + uploadFolder + thumbnailName;
                        myVideo.addEventListener('ended', function() {
                        myVideo.load();     
                        });
                        $("#dialog").dialog({
                         //Some data for dialog
                        });
}, 1000);
            }
         });
```

upload_video.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//Delete files if user click on abort
//Need some mod...
if (isset($_POST["deleteVideo"]) && isset($_POST["deleteThumb"])) {
    unlink($_POST["deleteVideo"]);
    unlink($_POST["deleteThumb"]);
}

//Create thumbnail
if (isset($_REQUEST['saveCanvas']) && isset($_POST["uploadFolder"])) {
    $img = $_POST['imgBase64'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    // $img       = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $fileThumb = $_POST['thumbnailName'];
    $uploadFolder = $_POST["uploadFolder"];
    $success = file_put_contents($uploadFolder . $fileThumb, $data);
    print $success ? $fileThumb : 'Unable to save the file.';
}

//File uploader
$return['status'] = 0;
if (isset($_FILES['vFile'])) {
    $conn_id = ftp_connect("");
    $ftp_user_name = "";
    $ftp_user_pass = "";

    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

    define( 'FORUM_PATH', '/home/full/patch/');
    require_once( FORUM_PATH . 'patch/to/member/api_member_login.php' );
    $ipbMemberLoginApi = new apiMemberLogin();
    $ipbMemberLoginApi->init();
    $member = $ipbMemberLoginApi->getMember();
    $memberId = ($member['member_id']);
    $upload_folder = 'uploads/' . $memberId . '/' . date("Y_m") . '/';
    if (!is_dir($upload_folder)) mkdir($upload_folder, 0777, true); 

    $name = $_FILES['vFile']['name'];
    $extension = explode('.', $name);
    $extension = end($extension);
    $type = $_FILES['vFile']['type'];
    //$size = $_FILES['vFile']['size'] / 1024 / 1024;
    $video_thumb_name = uniqid('video_' . $memberId . '_', false);
    $videoName = $video_thumb_name . '.' . $extension;
    $source_file = $_FILES['vFile']['tmp_name'];
    $destination_file = "/video/" . $upload_folder . $videoName;

    if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {
        $return['status'] = 0;
        exit;
    }
    else {
        if ($_FILES["vFile"]["type"] == "video/mp4") {
            $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);
            //Send variables to JS
            $return['videoName'] = $videoName;
            $return['thumbName'] = $video_thumb_name . '.png';
            $return['upload_folder'] = $upload_folder;
            $return['status'] = 1;
        }
        else {
            $return['error'] = 'Error Bla Bla Bla';
        }
        echo json_encode($return);
    }
    ftp_close($conn_id);

}
sleep(1);
?>
```

Это миниатюра нужно для постер.

Если плохой интернет, или какой то проблема, миниатюра не грузится в диалоговом окне, не показывается и получаю **404 (Not Found)** но он точно создан и сохранен.

---

**.on('error', function()...** Но, не красиво получается обновить постер после открытия окна:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/video/upload_video.php?saveCanvas=1",
                data: {
                    imgBase64: dataURL,
                    thumbnailName: thumbnailName,
                    uploadFolder: uploadFolder,
                    success: function() {

                            myVideo.currentTime = 0;
                            myVideo.load();
                            myVideo.poster = 'siteURL' + uploadFolder + thumbnailName;
//Если получаем ошибку 404
$('#myVideo').on('error', function() {
    $('#myVideo').attr('poster', 'siteURL' + uploadFolder + thumbnailName);
})
                            myVideo.addEventListener('ended', function() {
                            myVideo.load();     
                            });
                            $("#dialog").dialog({
                             //Some data for dialog
                            });

                }
             });
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так

```
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/video/upload_video.php?saveCanvas=1",
            data: {
                imgBase64: dataURL,
                thumbnailName: thumbnailName,
                uploadFolder: uploadFolder,
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data != 'Unable to save the file.') {
                      //Some data
                    }
            }
         });
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, в первом посте не было информация для чего и почему нужно править код. Добавил и поправил скрипт.  Протестировал ваш код, но проблема остается. Миниатюра иногда не показывается.